# если в пропсах приходит пустой объект, то рендерить предыдущий пришедший в пропсах объект?

Tags: reactjs

Через какой метод жизненного цикла сделать следующую проверку

если в пропсах приходит пустой объект, то рендерить предыдущий пришедший в пропсах объект.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю стоит воспользоваться `state` и методом `componentWillReceiveProps`:

```
state = {
   obj: {},
}

componentDidMount() {
   this.setState({obj: this.props.yourObject})
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
   if (Object.keys(nextProps.yourObject).length) {
      this.setState({obj: nextProps.yourObject)}
   }
}
```

Тогда у вас просто не поменяется состояние, если пришел пустой объект.